# QueryDSL join on multiple entities with one way relationships

Tags: querydsl

I have some entities similar to the following (psuedocode)

```
class A {
    Integer aId;
}

class B {
    Integer bId;

    @ManyToOne
    A a;
}

class C {
    Integer cId;

    @ManyToOne
    A a;
}
```

I'd like to use QueryDSL to get a list of B based on criteria in C.  I'd like not to have to create a Set of B or a Set of C in A.

If I do

```
query.from(b, c).innerJoin(b.a, a).fetch().innerJoin(c.a, a).
    where(c.cId.eq(1)).list(b);
```

then, as expected, I get a cross join.

If I do

```
query.from(b).innerJoin(b.a, a).fetch().innerJoin(c.a, a).
    where(c.cId.eq(1)).list(b);
```

then, as expected, I get an "Undeclared path" error.

I can do

```
query.from(b, c).innerJoin(b.a, a).fetch().innerJoin(c.a, a).
    where(c.cId.eq(1)).where(c.a.aId.eq(a.aId).list(b);
```

This keeps the cross join but does limit the results based on the where clause.  I wonder if there is a way to do this without the cross join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changes to the entity types you will need to use a cross join to connect the entities in the query.